# Which Archimate element should I use to model a shop

Tags: archimate

I'm in the process of creating various archimate models for my organization. We offer financial services. Customers can do most of the things they require using the online portal and the mobile app.

But we also have branch offices where customers can go to get personal attention. They can get personal advice, they can ask representatives for operational tasks, or they can go to a public workstation there and do it themselves using the online portal, potentially with some assistance.

How should I model such a branch office in Archimate? Is it an Actor? Or a Business Service? Or a Business Interface? Or maybe a Product? Or just a Location? It's also a thing that's designed around a specific concept, and we have different concepts, each with a unique setup and capabilities.

You can compare such a branch office with a retail shop, or a post office. It's more than an internal element, because this is a point of contact with your customer. But what kind of element best describes it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different type of elements to model a branch office:
If you use physical elements, the branch can be a "Facility".
But probably it fits more with a "Location" that can aggregate "Resources" (Strategy Elements) o "Business Roles" that can realize "Business Services".

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I feel both Facility and Location fail to show that the shop is a customer facing something. In many ways a shop is a value proposition, or closely related to that. It's obviously a grouping of several different things, but what type of element is the group itself. I think the grouping element should be associated to, or assigned to a location, but it isn't a location itself.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Consider this image, the customer is served various services (like personal advice) at (or aggregated in) a location assigned to the physical facility. Hope this answers your doubt.